# Debug dnsmasq not loading conf?

Tags: dnsmasq

On my laptop Ubuntu 16.04 I place a conf file at `/etc/dnsmasq.d/myApp.conf` with:

```
custom.myApp.com=192.168.12.1
```

Then I turn an Access Point on 192.168.12.1 and I can `nmap custom.myApp.com` to see all my ports mirrored.

Yet when I try the same thing on an embedded device running Ubuntu 14.04 my settings don't seem to take effect.

The `dnsmasq` versions are `2.75` and `2.68`. Is there a way I can check what configuration files are being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [changelog here](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/CHANGELOG). I'm thinking `2.72` added the functionality I'm using to load `dnsmasq.d/*`.

```
Version 2.72 
    ...
    Extend --conf-dir to allow filtering of files. So
    --conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d,\*.conf
    will load all the files in /etc/dnsmasq.d which end in .conf
```